# Why Apache IoTDB turned to read-only mode when doing large amounts of data writing?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

When doing large amount writing execution in Apache IoTDB, an error is reported: `org.apache.iotdb.rpc.StatementExecutionException: 302: Fail to do non-query operations because system is read-only`, and the system has turned to read-only when I did not set this way. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your disk space is full for the Apache IoTDB system. You can clear your disk and see if this read-only mode of IoTDB can be changed.